# How to have excel formula refresh when new data inserted with Java through Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am inserting a list of numbers into a column in Excel (column A) with Java. the following column has a list of average numbers (Column B). Column C has a list of formulas like this: =IF(B1 < 1,0,((A1)-B1)/B1).

In my program, I want to have the formulas in column C re-evaluate after I've input the new data so then I can extract the new cell value into Java. I'm checking to see if any new result in column C is -1.0.

I've tried to use FormulaEvaluator before extracting column C values but I still get the old values. I've also tried writing and closing the workbook and opening it again but that also hasn't worked.

```
   //Pull the values stored procedure   
    ResultSet rs = dbutils.sqlserverdbvaliation(query, db);
    System.out.println("Returned the Result Set");

    //Get number of rows in result row to set array size 
    rs.last();
    arraySize = rs.getRow();
    rs.beforeFirst();

    //Store values from resultSet into an array 
    int[] dlArray = new int[arraySize];
    while(rs.next()) {
         //Activity Process Count is name of ResultSet Column
        dlArray[count] = rs.getInt("ActivityProcessCount");
        count++;
    }

    //Create workbook 
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:\\TestWorkbook.xlsx");
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(1);
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = 
   wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    evaluator.evaluateAll();




    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dlArray));



    //Write the values from the array to the spreadsheet 
    int excelCount = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize ; i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(excelCount);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue(dlArray[i]);
        evaluator.evaluateAll();
        excelCount++;
    }
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\TestWorkbook.xlsx");
    evaluator.evaluateAll();
    wb.write(fos);
    wb.close();

    InputStream inp2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\TestWorkbook.xlsx");
    Workbook wb2 = WorkbookFactory.create(inp2);
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet2 = wb2.getSheetAt(1);

    excelCount = 1;

     for (int i = 0; i < arraySize ; i++) {
            Row row = sheet2.getRow(excelCount);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(4);
        if (cell.getNumericCellValue() == -1.0) {
            ExcelUtils.setCellStyle(excelPath, sheetName,  excelCount, 5, 
 YELLOW);
        }
        else {
            ExcelUtils.setCellStyle(excelPath, sheetName, excelCount, 5, 
 GREEN);
        }
        excelCount++;
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _" My issue is that even after using FormulaEvalutor to re-run the formulas, it still will not give me the new right value"_  -- WHERE do you not see correct values?  In later code in your program?  When you open the workbook in Excel?  The question is not answerable in its current form.  Can you reduce the problem to a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, that someone could copy/paste and run?  This has the potential to be a useful question, but needs elaboration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39418617/18157?

Comment: I've changed the question, let me see if I can simplify the code to make it easily run

Comment: In example provided the formulas are being passed through. Mine are already on the spreadsheet. I can try that approach

Comment: I set the cells of column C to formula type then passed the formulas through and re-evaluated them. It worked perfectly. Thanks!