# Formula cell does not get evaluated until formula is focussed and confirmed in Excel (XLSX)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, formula

So I use Apache POI (poi-ooxml in the latest stable release version 5.0.0) and open an **existing** Excel (XSLX) file for editing (it is basically a template file to populate with additional data). I add multiple new rows of data and export the Excel again. All works fine, as long as I only add regular content cells.

Now, I have one column where I want to add a formula cell, I use the following (simplified for this example, you can be assured that in general it compiles/runs and generates a populated Excel file at the end) code to do so:

```
File excelFileToRead = new File(<some filename here>);
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(excelFileToRead);
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Row dateRangeRow = sheet.getRow(0);

// fill first cell with some date
Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
if(cell == null) row.createCell(0)
Date someDate = new Date();
cell.setCellValue(someDate);

// add formula to second cell to display the week number
Cell formCell = row.getCell(1);
if(formCell == null) row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellFormula("WEEKNUM(A1)");

// evaluate all formula fields before saving
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);

//some routine to save as a file follows here, not exactly relevant here
```

In general, this works fine. The first cell is created and populated with today's date, the second cell also gets created as a formula cell.

Now here comes the problem: When I open the Excel spreadsheet, I can see the data and in the formula cell I only see "#WERT" (using German Excel, I assume in the English version it would show something like "#VALUE").

When I simply click into the fomula editor in Excel and remove the focus again, it evaluates the formula correctly and the cell shows the correct week number.

I had some issues before with pre-existing formulas in the Excel I read, that they got not updated when I added data to the sheet, but that could be fixed with the call to `XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);`
For some reason, it does not affect my custom created formula cells.

I also tried to individually evaluate the newly created formula cells after creation:

```
FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
formulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(formCell);
```

This produced no changes here either.

Any idea what is wrong in my code or approach in general?

I use Excel version 16.53 (Excel for Mac) by the way, but I really hope it is not related to the exact Excel version :-)

Note:
I found an old thread (way before POI 5.0.0 has been released) that seemed to discuss the very same issue, but with an older POI Version and also as stated above, I followed the general practice of calling evaluateAllFormulaCells(...) before saving and even called evaluateFormulaCell(cell) after each formula cell creation: [Apache POI formulas not evaluating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418617/apache-poi-formulas-not-evaluating)

Comment: Your code is very confusing. What is `CellReference.convertNumToColString(cell)`? `CellReference.convertNumToColString` needs a `int` and not a `Cell`. And why do you set the formula into the cell where you formerly had set the date in? That cannot work at all.

Comment: as stated before the code was simplified and you can rest assured it works in my real code basis where I acutally used cell.getColumnIndex() which I simply forgot while porting my example. I updated the above script to represent the actual code in this regards. It migh seem confusing here, but in my acutal example I deal with variable column and row indexes that are defined within some surrounding loops and as function paramerters. So I needed to evaluate those parameters dynamically. Since it does not realy matter for the core of my issue, I replaced the code with fixed values for now

Comment: you are of course right that it should be an int value not cell instance...and it is an int value in my actual code I use: cell.getColumnIndex()
was simply a mistake in porting the example / shortening my real code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This results from a bug in `apache poi` while evaluating [WEEKNUM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weeknum-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340) function.

If `[return_type]` is omitted then ist always evaluates to `#VALUE` error. But even if you set `[return_type]` then it evaluates not always correct.

You can see this if you do:

```
...
FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
CellValue cellValue = formulaEvaluator.evaluate(formCell);
System.out.println(cellValue);
...
```

If `A1` contains the date `9/27/2021` and `B1` contains the formula `=WEEKNUM(A1)` then `apache poi` `FormulaEvaluator` evaluates this to `#VALUE`. If `B1` contains the formula `=WEEKNUM(A1,1)` then `apache poi` `FormulaEvaluator` evaluates this to `39`, but `Excel` evaluates this to `40`.

To work around this bug, one can force `Excel` to calculate all formulas while opening the file. This can be done using `wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);`. Then `Excel` evaluates the formulas and so the results are correct.

Complete Example to reproduce the issue:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class CreateExcelFormulaWEEKNUM {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (
       //Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelIn.xls")); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./ExcelOut.xls");
       Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelIn.xlsx")); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./ExcelOut.xlsx");
        ) {

   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   Row row = sheet.getRow(0); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.getCell(0); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue(new GregorianCalendar(2021, 8, 27));
   CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(cell);
   
   Cell formCell = row.getCell(1); if(formCell == null) formCell = row.createCell(1);
   formCell.setCellFormula("WEEKNUM(" + cellReference.formatAsString() + ")"); // FormulaEvaluator evaluates to #VALUE because of [return_type] is not set
   //formCell.setCellFormula("WEEKNUM(" + cellReference.formatAsString() + ", 1)"); // FormulaEvaluator evaluates to 39 which is wrong as Excel evaluates to 40
   
   FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
   CellValue cellValue = formulaEvaluator.evaluate(formCell);
   System.out.println(cellValue);
   
   BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);
  
   wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

   wb.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Is there a bug for the `WEEKNUM` issue?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Yes, now there is: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65606

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the solution/workaround I needed, now all is fine when I open the Excel the first time

Comment: I've put some fixes in on POI trunk for issue 65606 - could probably do with more polish before release though.